# Url routing with parameters not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting

Here is my action link

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item1.TranslatedName,"Index","Properties",new { CategoryId=item1.CategoryId,CategoryName=item.CategoryName},null)
```

The url that is currently generated is 
    http://abc.com/Properties/?CategoryId=1&CategoryName=Banken
Also it doesnot calls the index view for the controller.If i change the url manually to
http://abc.com/Properties/Index?CategoryId=1&CategoryName=Banken
it works

the route that i have defined for this is

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Properties", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{CategoryId}/{CategoryName}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Properties", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
            new { CategoryId = @"\d+", CategoryName = @"\d+" }
        );
```

Can anybody tell what am i doing wrong?

The Url that i need to be displayed is 
  http://abc.com/Properties/Banken
basically i want to hide the category id and display the categoryName instead

Comment: 1. Is this route defined before the default route? (for problem1) 2. You cannot hide an intermediate(not the last) route segment.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it like Properties/Banken, you should rename your index action to banken action, also i'm not sure if you can hide the id